# Sending linux commands over serial

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, adb, shell, command-line

I have a question about being able to send Linux commands over a serial connection to an Android device.

I have heard of **putty** and tried to use it, but i am ultimately lost with it. Like if I was in the Linux shell of the Android and could type, `reboot` and the device would reboot. The Android device has a virtual serial connection, and I have been able to connect to it using **putty**, but I don't know where to go after that. I know this is confusing and may be completely wrong, thank you for your time in advance.

I also have been able to connect to it with **QPST**, and see a 100mb drive come up with some files in it.

Answer (score 0):

what do you want to do with linux commands?.You can check for devices in the i2c bus and you'll get to see the debug messages.If you want to test something specifically  please mention it.